# Estimate Integral w.r.t Dirac measure by Integral w.r.t Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given a bounded, nonnegative and measurable function $f$ and denote the Euclidean ball with center $z$ and radius $r$ by $B_r(z)$.

Is it somehow possible to estimate the Integral w.r.t. the Dirac Lebesgue measure by the Integral w.r.t the Lebesgue measure?

I.e. is something like $\int_{B_r(z)} f(x) \delta_z (dx) \leq \int_{B_r(z)} f(x) dx$ true (maybe with some positive constant on the r.h.s)?

I believe its false, because the l.h.s is simply $f(z)$ (which we can assume to be positive and not zero) while the r.h.s might be zero.

Comment: a lower bound is possible, not an upper bound.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: I'm not sure what kind of lower bound you have in mind, but taking $f = a \cdot 1_{\{z\}^C}$ seems to rule out such a thing.

Comment: right, my mistake.